# How to rm -rf a directory that's "hard to kill"?

Tags: linux

I want to `sudo rm -rf` a directory, it was a chrooted jail.  I already did everything I know of:

`umount` everything in there

`netns -k` the directory

`ps amx` kill everything involving the directory

`fuser` kill everything involving the directory

`lsof` kill everything involving the directory

and still it says some subdirectories are busy:

```
selinux
sys
dev
var/run/netns
log
proc
tmp/.X11-unix
```

I can no longer `chroot` in there and see if there is anything to kill, because some files got nuked the first time I tried `rm -rf`.

I cannot reboot the machine, it is not an option.

What else is there I don't know of?

I could also move this thing and forget about it (until the next reboot can be done).  But, also `mv` fails with the same errors.

Answer (score 1):

These are exactly the directories which have or can have something mounted to them. Is it sure, that you removed everything? What says a cat /proc/mounts ?

Comment: there is no such file

Comment: Then your system has a big trouble. The information, what is mounted to where, can be readable from the special files below /proc. lsof, fuser et al remains silent exactly because your /proc was somehow unmounted. First you should mount it back with a simple `mount /proc` command. After that, lsof, fuser et al will give you much better info back. Are you sure you aren't in your chroot?

Answer (score 0):

This is a "gotcha" about `lsof` !

Since `lsof` normally wants a file and I did not know what file might be used, I simply did

`lsof | grep` directory

to find out which processes are using all files inside the directory.

Wrong!  That is not the same as

`sudo lsof +D` directory

The first version will silently (without warning) not list anything it does not have permissions to look at.